# How to determine if a line in a file matches a wildcard expression?

Tags: python, if-statement, wildcard

How should I type in Python `if` condition to match wildcard expression (*)?

I am trying to find line(s) in file that match wildcard expression - ...string1*string2*string3...

```
with open(file,'rw') as FILE:
  lines = FILE.readlines()
  for line in lines:
       if line == "string1*string2*string3":
       print (line)
```

Comment: You can use `re`gex to `.findall` matches and use `if` condition on top of it.

Comment: Note that the regular expression would be `"string1.*string2.*string3"`.

Comment: Also note that `"rw"` is not a valid file mode.  I suspect you just wanted `"r"`.

Comment: I need to open, read and write in File at the same time. Edit with correction from Tim, works well. Thanks!

Comment: How could I append string to the start or beginning of that speicic line found by IF?

Comment: @Scripter use "r+" for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using regular expressions:

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path

mystring = re.compile('string1.*string2.*string3')
filename = Path('/path/to/some/file')

with filename.open() as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if mystring.match(line):
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample:

```
import re
with open(file,'r') as file:
  for line in file.readlines():
    if re.search( "string1.*string2.*string3", line ):
       print (line)
```

Of course, if this is ALL you're doing, you don't need Python at all:

```
grep 'string1.*string2.*string3'  file.txt
```

Or on Windows:

```
findstr /r "string1.*string2.*string3" file.txt
```

Comment: To be pythonic and conform with PEP8 you need to "fix" a few things: multiples of four spaces for indentation, `'r'` is the default for `open()` so there is no need to pass it, remove spaces inside `()`, `print()`  instead of `print ()`. Those are pet peeves for most but it is what a Pythonista would do if they are a real Pythonista.